# Using a while loop to output a list after user input

Tags: python, listview, while-loop

I'm new to python and im attempting for my program to output a the variable "movie genre" vertically once a user enters their name. I plan to use a while loop but keep hitting the error "movie_genre". And perplexed as to how to proceed.

```
def main():
    #Movie list
    movie_genre = ["Action", ["Horror"], ["Adventure"], ["Musical"], ["Comedy"], ["Sci-Fi"], ["Drama"], ["Romance"], ["Thriller"]]
    name = ''
    

#We introduce the program to the user 
print ("Hello my name is Frank, the theatre clerk!")

#Asks the user to input their name 
print ("May I please know who i have the pleasure of speaking with?")

#User submits name 
name = input("")

#Returns user name + prompt
print(name + ", pleasure to make your acquaintance!")

while name:
#Asks the user for what genre they want to watch 
    i = name ("What are we interested in watching today?")
    for x in zip (*movie_genre):
        print (x)
```

Comment: first edit question and use special function to format code - Ctrl+K or ``` (below `ESC`), not `'''`

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: is this your original indentations ? It is wrong. You create `movie_genre` inside `main()` - so it is local variable, but rest of code is outside function and it can't acccess local variables.

Comment: you use `input()` and `name` in wrong way. You can't use `name(...)` because `name` is a `string` - it seems you need `i = input(...)`.

Comment: you don't have to use space between function's name and `()` - ie. `print()`, `zip()`

Comment: I don't understand why you use `while name`. It will run forever because you don't change `name` inside this loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't show error message but if this is your original indentations then problem is that you create `movie_genre` inside function - so it is local variable which exists only inside function, but rest of code is outside function and it can't access it. You should move all code inside function or you should keep all code outside function.

I will keep all outside function - so I can remove it.

There are other mistakes and few elements which you could fix

You could keep genders withou inner `[]` and then you don't need `zip(*...)`

```
movie_genre = ["Action", "Horror", "Adventure", "Musical", "Comedy", "Sci-Fi", "Drama", "Romance", "Thriller"]

for genre in movie_genre:
    print(genre)
```

You use `name` in strange way in `i = name(..)` - `name` is a `string` and you can't use it like a function. Maybe you needed `input()` to ask for selected `genre` - `selected = input(...)` - but I would do this after displaying genres.

I also don't know what you want to do with `while name`. This will run loop forever because you doesn't change `name` inside loop. Maybe you need something different - ie. maybe you want to repeate loop until user select correct gender - `while selected not in movie_genre:

---

Full example

```
#Movie list
movie_genre = ["Action", "Horror", "Adventure", "Musical", "Comedy", "Sci-Fi", "Drama", "Romance", "Thriller"]
name = ''

#We introduce the program to the user 
print("Hello my name is Frank, the theatre clerk!")

#Asks the user to input their name 
print("May I please know who i have the pleasure of speaking with?")

#User submits name 
name = input()

#Returns user name + prompt
print(name + ", pleasure to make your acquaintance!")

# --- select genre ---
selected = ""  # default value before loop

while selected not in movie_genre:  # repeate until user select genre

    for genre in movie_genre:
        print(genre)

    #Asks the user for what genre they want to watch 
    selected = input("What are we interested in watching today?")
```

Answer (score 0):

`movie_genre` isn't defined in the same scope as where you are trying to use it.

This can be fixed in a variety of ways, either indent all of your code so it is under the same scope as the main function, and then call that function using `main()`

Or

A simpler fix is to just move the definition of `movie_genre` closer to where you will use it:

```
movie_genre = [["Action"], ["Horror"], ["Adventure"], ["Musical"], ["Comedy"], ["Sci-Fi"], ["Drama"], ["Romance"], ["Thriller"]]

if name:
#Asks the user for what genre they want to watch 
    print("What are we interested in watching today?")
    for x in zip(*movie_genre):
        print(x)
```

Comment: I see you fixed `i = name(...)` - you could describe it for OP. And I think it may need extra `[ ]` in `["Action"]` - other elements have `[ ]`

Comment: It will display `A` instead of `Action`. You could describe all problems in this code.

Comment: Feel free to post your answer to fix all of the other issues